# GUI for Ubuntu Server

Tags: installation, command-line, server, gui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a GUI environment with Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53574/how-to-get-a-gui-environment-with-ubuntu-server)

I'd like to do some work with Ubuntu Server software. I'm familiar with Ubuntu Linux and have a fair bit of experience with networking and server technology, but I'm not strong on the Linux command-line. I tried to install the latest version of Ubuntu server, but it was just a command line. Is there a GUI version of Ubuntu server OR and easy way to install one from the command line?

TIA

Comment: `sudo apt-get install lxde xorg` or `sudo apt-get install xfce4 xorg` is a couple of possibilities

Answer (score 3):

You can install the desktop environment used in the desktop edition on top of your server install by doing:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

on your Ubuntu server installation.

Be warned, however, that unlike Windows, there's not much of a way to configure services and system settings via the GUI. If you plan to seriously use Ubuntu server, I strongly suggest you become comfortable and familiar with the shell.

Answer (score 3):

You can install a light environment, LXDE.  To install it, just run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install lxde
```

> As roadmr said, you'd better get comfortable, with the server command
>   line.

Thats how you get the better control over your server.  For more information see the

[Ubuntu Server Guide](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/serverguide.pdf&ei=1QFFUKvHBYb80QWZjoCwCQ&usg=AFQjCNFd4boLCsAgAJV_TZl7BHg54QGs2Q&sig2=w_zXyLhXCMJ9-E3Z0_NRZA&cad=rja)

For more information on how to install GUI on Ubuntu server see

[Ubuntu 12.04 Server – How to Install a GUI](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04-server/ubuntu-12-04-server-how-to-install-a-gui)

Comment: Unless I'm confused Ctrl+Alt+T is obviously unnecessary here, given that there is no desktop environment installed yet?

Answer (score -1):

For installing Unity desktop you can use following command:

```
sudo aptitude install --without-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

or for smaller package to download use:

```
sudo aptitude install --without-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Aptitude 0.6.8.2 does not recognize `--without-install-recommends`. I think you are confusing this flag with a similar one that exists for `apt-get` (`--no-install-recommends`).